# Different jQuery/JS errors in rails app with bootsrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bootstrap-sass

I have a filter that filters my form. When I open it my datepicker does not work even if the same code works on another page of the app. I do not get the error on the other pages.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

On every page I get

```
DEPRECATED: This filename doesn't follow the convention, use bootstrap-datepicker.en-CA.js instead.
$.fn.datepicker.deprecated @ core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker-en-CA.self-fb416403a677f41efad9cfc05939c9fe3eeb04627845d85da10d9eee99ba96b2.js?body=1:21
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker-en-CA.self-fb416403a677f41efad9cfc05939c9fe3eeb04627845d85da10d9eee99ba96b2.js?body=1:23
core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012 DEPRECATED: The language code "kh" is deprecated and will be removed in 2.0. For Khmer support use "km" instead.
$.fn.datepicker.deprecated @ core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.kh.self-6562a5a87f529e9a3121f8b49f20a6f7d3651340738f7d747a2418d721d01eae.js?body=1:21
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.kh.self-6562a5a87f529e9a3121f8b49f20a6f7d3651340738f7d747a2418d721d01eae.js?body=1:22
core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012 DEPRECATED: The language code "kr" is deprecated and will be removed in 2.0. For korean support use "ko" instead.
$.fn.datepicker.deprecated @ core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.kr.self-ca28b775db5a32ebbee6667b0bc40e26e078ce363db5c55c9a904155d3b9fdb5.js?body=1:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.kr.self-ca28b775db5a32ebbee6667b0bc40e26e078ce363db5c55c9a904155d3b9fdb5.js?body=1:20
core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012 DEPRECATED: This language code "rs-latin" is deprecated (invalid serbian language code) and will be removed in 2.0. For Serbian latin support use "sr-latin" instead.
$.fn.datepicker.deprecated @ core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.rs-latin.self-a3302a16cb7cc00b6d455f26ed8a73f8890da7280ee9507c2cd9fe9f36ec6352.js?body=1:20
(anonymous) @ bootstrap-datepicker.rs-latin.self-a3302a16cb7cc00b6d455f26ed8a73f8890da7280ee9507c2cd9fe9f36ec6352.js?body=1:21
core.self-c808be6e04274a80c551034d8f8a677b7c3995aec044ea4e6edf9cbbc19ff750.js?body=1:2012 DEPRECATED: This language code "rs" is deprecated (invalid serbian language code) and will be removed in 2.0. For Serbian support use "sr" instead.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (bootstrap.self-fdc98dee79ee88255e10cac6caa91338165cb76cf0d263744d8d90011fc2ef8f.js?body=1:3)
at fire (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3233)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3363)
at Function.ready (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3583)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:3618)
```

and I googled that this comes from importing jQuery twice. But my

***application.js***

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

imports it just once and even the order should be ok.

***html.erb***

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <% provide(:title, "Mitarbeiter hinzufügen") %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div>
  <%= form_for :anything, url: add_worker_tm_trainings_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :schicht %>
    <%= f.collection_select :shift, Shift.all, :id, :name, include_blank: :true %>
    <div class="lineshow">
    <%= f.label :linie %>
    <%= f.collection_select :line, Line.all, :id, :name, include_blank: :true %>
    <%= f.submit "submit", :class => 'submit_button' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  <div class="realform">
    <%= form_with model: Trainingsmembership, url: add_worker_tm_trainings_path do |f| %>
  <div style="overflow: auto; height: 350px">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 25px"></th>
        <th style="width: 200px"><%= sort_link "name" %></th>
        <th style="width: 125px"><%= sort_link "position" %></th>
        <th style="width: 75px"><%= sort_link "Schicht" %></th>
        <th style="width: 100px"><%= sort_link "linie" %></th>
      </tr>
      <% @workers.each do |worker| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "worker_ids[worker_ids][]", worker.id %></td>
          <td><%= worker.name %></td>
          <td><%= Position.find(worker.position_id).name %></td>
          <td><%= Shift.find(worker.shift_id).name %></td>
          <td><% worker.line_ids.each do |line| %>
              <%= Line.find(line).name %>
            <% end %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 350px">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 25px"></th>
          <th style="width: 200px"><%= sort_link "Training" %></th>
          <th style="width: 100px"><%= sort_link "linie" %></th>
        </tr>
        <% @trainingall.each do |training| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "training_ids[training_ids][]", training.id %></td>
            <td><%= training.name %></td>
            <td><%= Line.find(training.where_lines).name %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    </div>
  <br><br>
    <%= f.label "Gültigkeit" %>
    <%= f.text_field :duration%>
    <%= f.label "Prüfungstermin" %>
    <%= f.text_field :date%>
    <%= f.label "Bemerkung" %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment%>
    <%= f.label "PDF-Protokoll" %>
    <%= f.text_field :attachement%>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  <!-- %= f.input :training_id, collection: @trainings, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: 'Training:', include_blank: false %>
  %= f.input :duration, label: 'Gültigkeit:' %>
  %= f.input :date, :as => :string, :input_html => { data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}}, label: 'Prüfungstermin:' %>

  %= f.input :comment, as: :text, label: 'Bemerkung:' %>
  %= f.input :attachement, as: :file, label: 'PDF-Protokoll:' %>
  %= f.submit "Training bearbeiten", class: "btn btn-primary" %-->
    <!--#%= f.input :worker_id, collection: Worker.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: 'Mitarbeiter', include_blank: false, input_html: { multiple: false } %>-->
<% end %>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.lineshow').hide();
          $('.realform').hide();
          $('#anything_shift').change(function () {
              if($('#anything_shift option:selected').text != ""){
                  $('.lineshow').show();
              }
          });
          $('#anything_line').change(function () {
              if($('#anything_line option:selected').text != ""){
                  $('.realform').show();
              }
          });
          $("submit").click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/trainings/add_worker_tm",
                  data: {
                      id: $(this).val(),
                      access_token: $("access_token").val()
                  },
                  success: function (result) {
                      $('.realform').show();
                  }
              })
          })
      });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function() {
        var size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
        if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
            alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
        }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
        "format": "dd.mm.yyyy",
        "weekStart": 1,
        "autoclose": true
    });
</script>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The ajax call is not working as well but I had not invested much time in it yet. I do not like the first line there but without my jQuery seems not working, but why? I think I included jQuery in my application.js...

***controller.erb***

```
def add_worker_tm
    if !params.has_key?(:anything)
      puts "emoty"
    @worker = Worker.new
    @workers = Worker.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    @workerall = Worker.all
    @trainings = Training.all
    @trainingall = Training.all
    else
      @shift = params[:anything].require(:shift)
      @line = params[:anything].require(:line)
      @worker = Worker.new
      @workersshifts = Worker.all.where("shift_id= ?", @shift)
      puts @workersshifts
      @workers = []
      @workersshifts.each do |w|
        puts w.line_ids
          if w.line_ids.include? @line
            @workers << w
        end
      end
      @workerall = Worker.all
      @trainings = Training.all.where(where_lines: @line)
      @trainingall = Training.all.where(where_lines: @line)
    end
    end

  def add_worker_tm
if !params.has_key?(:anything)
  puts "empty"
@worker = Worker.new
@workers = Worker.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
@workerall = Worker.all
@trainings = Training.all
@trainingall = Training.all
else
  @shift = params[:anything].require(:shift)
  @line = params[:anything].require(:line)
  @worker = Worker.new
  @workersshifts = Worker.where(shift_id: @shift)
  @workers = []
  @workersshifts.each do |w|
      if !w.line_ids.include?(@line)
        @workers << w
    end
  end
  @workerall = Worker.all
  @trainings = Training.all.where(where_lines: @line)
  @trainingall = Training.all.where(where_lines: @line)
end
end
```

My controller is fine I think, I fixed my filter bug and it displays what I want.

Now my questions:

1. How can I fix the bootstrap js/jQuery errors?
2. How can I make the datepicker working again?
3. What do I need to change, that my AJAX call works correctly and displays my filtered tables without any refresh?

I am very confused and should add that I am very new to rails, jQuery and js.

Comment: Try removing `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>` from the view.

Comment: Ok, I do not get the error with the datepicker, though it is not working and my hidden parts are all shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours try and error, I found some solutions.

I found out that turbolinks are evil and do not trigger all my events. After I found out, I deleted `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>` and changed my script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
          $('.lineshow').hide();
          $('.realform').hide();
```

Now it is working.

My datepicker seems like not working cause of my previous jQuery-Script so I made it to a simple_form_for and the picker is there again. I put the whole form in a partial.

```
    <div>
  <%= form_for :anything, :html=>{:id=>"filter", :multipart => true,:remote=>true}, url: add_worker_tm_trainings_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :schicht %>
    <%= f.collection_select :shift, Shift.all, :id, :name, include_blank: :true %>
    <div class="lineshow">
      <%= f.label :linie %>
      <%= f.collection_select :line, Line.all, :id, :name, include_blank: :true %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
      <%= f.submit "filter", {:class => "bttn-and-txt", :id => "filter", :name => "filter", :value => "filter"} %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="realform">
    <%= simple_form_for(Trainingsmembership.new, url: add_worker_tm_trainings_path) do |f| %>
      <div style="overflow: auto; height: 350px">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 25px"></th>
            <th style="width: 200px"><%= sort_link "name" %></th>
            <th style="width: 125px"><%= sort_link "position" %></th>
            <th style="width: 75px"><%= sort_link "Schicht" %></th>
            <th style="width: 100px"><%= sort_link "linie" %></th>
          </tr>
          <% @workers.each do |worker| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "worker_ids[worker_ids][]", worker.id %></td>
              <td><%= worker.name %></td>
              <td><%= Position.find(worker.position_id).name %></td>
              <td><%= Shift.find(worker.shift_id).name %></td>
              <td>
                <% worker.line_ids.each do |line| %>
                  <%= Line.find(line).name %>
                <% end %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow: auto; height: 350px">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 25px"></th>
            <th style="width: 200px"><%= sort_link "Training" %></th>
            <th style="width: 100px"><%= sort_link "linie" %></th>
          </tr>
          <% @trainingall.each do |training| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "training_ids[training_ids][]", training.id %></td>
              <td><%= training.name %></td>
              <td><%= Line.find(training.where_lines).name %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </table>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <%= f.input :duration, label: 'Gültigkeit:' %>
      <%= f.input :date, :as => :string, :input_html => { data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}}, label: 'Prüfungstermin:' %>
      <%= f.input :comment, as: :text, label: 'Bemerkung:' %>
      <%= f.input :attachement, as: :file, label: 'PDF-Protokoll:' %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
      <%= f.submit "Mitarbeiter hinzufügen", {:class => "btn btn-primary", :name => "submit", :value => "submit"} %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
          "format": "dd.mm.yyyy",
          "weekStart": 1,
          "autoclose": true
      });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function GetCookie(name) {
          var arg=name+"=";
          var alen=arg.length;
          var clen=document.cookie.length;
          var i=0;

          while (i<clen) {
              var j=i+alen;
              if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
                  return "here";
              i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
              if (i==0)
                  break;
          }

          return null;
      };
      document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
          $('.lineshow').hide();
          //$('.realform').hide();

              var visit=GetCookie("COOKIE1");

              if (visit==null){
                  $('.realform').hide();
              }
              var expire=new Date();
              expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+(5*60*1000));
              document.cookie="COOKIE1=here; expires="+expire;

          $('#anything_shift').change(function () {
              if ($('#anything_shift option:selected').text != "") {
                  $('.lineshow').show();
              }
          });
          $('#anything_line').change(function () {
              if ($('#anything_line option:selected').text != "") {
                  $("#filter").click();
              }
          });

      });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#micropost_picture').bind('change', function () {
          var size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024;
          if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
              alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
          }
      });
  </script>
</div>
```

With these javascripts and *form.js.erb* `$("#filter").html("<%= j(render 'tform').html_safe %>")` and in my controller I needed to add this before the end of the methods

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'trainings/add_worker_tm'}
      format.html
    end
```

everything looks like working. The cookies are a dirty solution to make it possible that a different request to the filter will be shown immediately.

Comment: You can just remove turbolinks gem from your gemfile if you don't want it. I'd recomend to read the Turbolinks documentation on github anyway, since it's actually easy to use.

Comment: I rather keep it. To remove a feature that speeds up my page is not a great solution. I am new to rails, js/jQuery and ajax so I have trouble with it, but I learned enough to not remove turbolinks. Thanks for the suggestion, I will read it.

Comment: Do you know a better way than cookies that I can show every new filter request on the page? If I do not use my cookie the *realform* will be hidden the first time and shown the second...